# Progress dots with a Thread in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, progress-bar, python-multithreading

I am trying to create a thread in Python that will poll some server as long as it won't get proper answer (HTTP GET). In order to provide convenient text UI I want to print progress dots. Another dot with every connection attempt until it finish (or just another dot with every another second of waiting).

I have found something like this: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/535141-console-progress-dots-using-threads-and-a-context-/

In this example we have context manager:

```
with Ticker("A test"):
    time.sleep(10)
```

I am not sure if I understand that properly. I would like to do something like:

```
with Ticker("A test: "):      
    result = -1
    while result != 0:
        result = poll_server()
    print "Finished."
```

But this does not work. Any ideas?

Cheers

Comment: Does the first example work, and the second one not? In what way does it not work?

Comment: What is poll_server, does it call C code?

Answer (score 0):

Python buffers your output, so many dots will appear at once. One way around that is to `import sys` and use that: whenever you want to print a dot, say:

```
sys.stdout.write(".")
sys.stdout.flush()
```

The flush makes the dot appear immediately.

Answer (score 0):

```py
#! /usr/bin/python3
import sys
import time


def progress(message):
    i = 0
    while True:
        dots = ""
        i = (i % 3) + 1
        dots += "." * i + " " * (3 - i)
        sys.stdout.write("\r{}".format(message + dots))
        sys.stdout.flush()
        i += 1
        time.sleep(0.3)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    progress("Waiting")
```

More useful example:

```py
#! /usr/bin/python3
import sys
import time


def progress_gen(message):
    i = 0
    while True:
        for x in range(0, 4):
            dots = "." * x
            sys.stdout.write("{}\r".format(message + dots))
            i += 1
            time.sleep(0.5)
        sys.stdout.write("\033[K")
        yield


if __name__ == "__main__":
    p = progress_gen("Waiting")

    for x in range(1, 100):
        next(p)
        if x == 3:
            break

    print("Finished")
```

You can test it online: https://repl.it/@binbrayer/DotsProgress